# Получить часовой пояс города

Tags: javascript, php, xls, libre-office

Есть файл xls (пример) содержит название нас. пункта; координаты х,у; часовой пояс; 
 Мне необходимо указать часовые пояса относительно Лондона. Можно ли как то автоматизировать этот процесс
Может есть какая нибудь формула в libreOffice чтобы использовать координаты или имя нас.пункта чтобы заполнить столбец с часовым поясом. 
 Или как то может с помощью скрипта на php, js.

[image: координаты]

Comment: официальный часовой пояс идентифицируется только по регионам и областям английскими буквами. Пояс по солнцу = долгота / 360 * 24 = долгота / 15

Comment: для чего пояс по солнцу?

Comment: в PHP если точно область знаете то так [date_default_timezone_get](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) , а если у вас только долгота то только на глаз, глядя на солнце.

Comment: не совсем то, мне необходимо что то будет возвращать число(GMT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Maps Time Zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/overview)

[Bing Maps Time Zone API](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/bingmaps/rest-services/timezone/)

[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/timezone)

Библиотека на [PHP](https://github.com/minube/geo-timezone)
Библиотека на JS [тут](https://github.com/mapbox/timespace) и [тут](https://github.com/darkskyapp/tz-lookup-oss/)

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).